# Idiom or phrase to indicate that mere sympathy does not help

Tags: phrases, idioms

Are there any **idioms** or **phrases** to indicate that **mere sympathy does not make a good case** in the context of the following sentence?

> Instead of proving his innocence, he relied on his personal stories. **Mere sympathy does not make a good case**, so he needs to bring evidence.

Comment: A sympathy? What is a sympathy?

Comment: Beyond [*tugging at our heartstrings*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tug%2Fpull%20at%20one%27s%20heartstrings), he needs to bring evidence.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin *Beyond* isn't quite right here. Do you mean *instead of* or *as well as*? Or perhaps it's a US usage.

Comment: Found out again.

Comment: @oldbrixtonian, should the word beyond be replace or it can stand in the context of the present sentence

Comment: See my answer below but vote for Yosef Baskin's first comment!

Comment: 'An appeal to sympathy', not 'sympathy'.

Comment: Sounds like he's telling a _sob story_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, are we in the present or the past? **He needs** is in the present tense: **He relied** is in the past tense.

> In order to prove his innocence he needs to produce evidence, rather
> than simply tugging at our heartstrings with his personal stories.

Changing 'needs' to 'needed' will move the sentence into the past tense.

Yosef Baskin supplied the perfect expression.

Answer (score 4):

To mean that actions, not just words, are needed, you could say:

**Fine words butter no parsnips.**

This is an old English expression, but you still hear it occasionally.  It refers to the practice of mashing root vegetables with butter (a potentially strenuous task), and also to ‘[buttering up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butter_up)’ in the sense of flattery.

(More details [here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/fine-words-butter-no-parsnips.html), and in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140835/why-do-fine-words-butter-no-parsnips).)

Answer (score 3):

In [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_pity), this is the *argumentum ad misericordiam*, or the appeal to pity.

Comment: Thats more a description of what such a phrase is rather than the phrase itself - or for that matter, idiom.